# If resultset is not scrollable then absolute function should not work

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Hi I am new to JDBC concept and as per my knowledge to move the resultset pointer in both direction resultset needs to be set **scrollable**

But since the resultset is not set to scrollable **absolute** function should not allow the pointer to move back

but the below code is working fine

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from studentinfo");  
    int counter=0;
    while(rs.next()) 
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));
        int row = rs.getRow();
        if(row==5)
        {
            if(counter==0)
            {
                counter++;
                rs.absolute(4);
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
    }
    con.close();
```

In this code, I am moving the pointer back to the **4th row** if the current row is **equal to 5th**

and as you can see I haven't given any parameter in createStatement() method i.e. by **default** it should be ** nonscrollable** and hence above code should not fetch results however its working fine how so?

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? Perhaps that particular driver only implement **scrollable**, which is compatible with **forward-only**, so that shouldn't be an issue. Try calling `getResultSetType()` to see. But why do you care? If you want to use `absolute()`, ask for **scrollable**, and it should work with all drivers.

Comment: @Andreas how to use getResultSetType()

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getType--

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jdbc/9172/resultset#t=201703261140142179499

Answer (score 2):

The [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html) says:

> The default `ResultSet` type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.
>
> The method `DatabaseMetaData.supportsResultSetType` returns `true` if the
>   specified type is supported by the driver and `false` otherwise.
>
> If the driver does not support the type supplied to the methods `createStatement`,
>   `prepareStatement`, or `prepareCall`, it generates an `SQLWarning` on the
>   `Connection` object that is creating the statement. When the statement is executed,
>   the driver returns a `ResultSet` object of a type that most closely matches the
>   requested type. An application can find out the type of a `ResultSet` object by
>   calling the method `ResultSet.getType`.

- Check if `TYPE FORWARD_ONLY` is supported by your JDBC driver.
- Check if you get an `SQLWarning`.
- Check what `ResultSet` type you got.